# Is my understanding of rolling horizon correct?

Tags: optimization

I would appreciate any feedback on my understanding of "rolling horizon in optimization".
I'll try to point out, what is my understanding of it.

*First in simple words:*

You have an optimization problem considering several timesteps. So the decision variables are additionally indexed in the set of timesteps $\mathcal{T}$. For example, in the first horizon $\mathcal{T}=\{0,1,2\}$, then in the next horizon it is $\mathcal{T}=\{1,2,3\}$ an then $\mathcal{T}=\{2,3,4\}$ and so on $\dots$

Then you solve the optimization problem for each horizon and get values for decision variables $\{x_0^0,x_1^0,x_2^0\}$ in the first horizon, than $\{x_1^1,x_2^1,x_3^1\}$ for the second horizon and $\{x_2^2,x_3^2,x_4^2\}$ for the third horizon, where the superscripts denote the number of the current horizon.

Then you take the first results of each horizon, so $x_0$ from the first horizon, $x_1$ from the second horizon and $x_2$ from the third horizon and so on. And you append it to a list of results, I will call it $X$, so $X=\{x_0^0,x_1^1,x_2^2\}$

Further, one has to make sure, that the horizons are coupled to each other, so the value of the first timestep of the second horizon is set to the second timestep of the first horizon, so that $x_1^1=x_1^0$, $x_2^2=x_2^1$, and so on $\dots$

*And now for the mathematical aspect:*

Let's consider the following problem: a company producing goods $x_{t,p}$ where $t\in\mathcal{T}:=\{0,1,2\}$ is the timestep and $p\in\mathcal{P}:=\{0,1\}$ is the type of good. Each good can be sold for a price $r_{t,p}$. But each good also needs some ressources to be created $c_{t,p,a}$ where $a\in\mathcal{A}:=\{0,1\}$ denotes the type of required ressource and $s_{t,a}$ is the available amount of each ressource. Only whole, positive numbers are allowed for the number of goods to produce.

So a formulation could be:
\begin{align}
\begin{split}
\mathrm{max.}\qquad&\sum_{t\in\mathcal{T}}\sum_{p\in\mathcal{P}}r_{t,p}\cdot x_{t,p}\\
\mathrm{s.t.}\qquad&\sum_{p\in\mathcal{P}}c_{t,p,a}\cdot x_{t,p}\leq s_{t,a}\qquad\forall a\in\mathcal{A}\quad\forall t\in\mathcal{T} \\
&x_{t,p}\in\mathbb{Z}^+\qquad\forall p\in\mathcal{P}\quad\forall t\in\mathcal{T}
\end{split}
\end{align}

Or formulated as matrices:

\begin{align}
    \begin{split}
    \mathrm{max.}\qquad&c^T \cdot x \\
    \mathrm{s.t.}\qquad&A\cdot x\leq b \\
    &x_i\in\mathbb{Z}^+\qquad\forall i\in\mathcal{I}
    \end{split}
\end{align}

And now the $A$, $b$ and $c$ change their values for different horizons. For example $c$ in the first horizon looks like:

\begin{equation}
    c^T=
    \begin{pmatrix}
        r_{0,0} \\
        r_{0,1} \\
        r_{1,0} \\
        r_{1,1} \\
        r_{2,0} \\
        r_{2,1} \\
    \end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}

but then in the next horizon it becomes:
\begin{equation}
    \label{c-vec}
    c^T=
    \begin{pmatrix}
        r_{1,0} \\
        r_{1,1} \\
        r_{2,0} \\
        r_{3,1} \\
        r_{3,0} \\
        r_{3,1} \\
    \end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
so the values seem to shift from the bottom to the top.

The same can be observed for $b$ and $x$:
\begin{equation}
    x=
    \begin{pmatrix}
        x_{0,0} \\
        x_{0,1} \\
        x_{1,0} \\
        x_{1,1} \\
        x_{2,0} \\
        x_{2,1} \\
    \end{pmatrix}
\to
\begin{pmatrix}
        x_{1,0} \\
        x_{1,1} \\
        x_{2,0} \\
        x_{2,1} \\
        x_{3,0} \\
        x_{3,1} \\
    \end{pmatrix}
\cdots
\end{equation}

And in the $A$ matrix the values seem to shift along the main diagonal:
\begin{equation}
    \label{A-mat}
    A=
    \begin{pmatrix}
        c_{0,0,0} & c_{0,0,1} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
        c_{0,1,0} & c_{0,1,1} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & c_{1,0,0} & c_{1,0,1} & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & c_{1,1,0} & c_{1,1,1} & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & c_{2,0,0} & c_{2,0,1} \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & c_{2,1,0} & c_{2,1,1} \\
    \end{pmatrix}
\to
\begin{pmatrix}
        c_{1,0,0} & c_{1,0,1} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
        c_{1,1,0} & c_{1,1,1} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & c_{2,0,0} & c_{2,0,1} & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & c_{2,1,0} & c_{2,1,1} & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & c_{3,0,0} & c_{3,0,1} \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & c_{3,1,0} & c_{3,1,1} \\
    \end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}

Sorry for the whole lot of text. But that is my current understanding of rolling horizon in optimization. Is it correct? And is there maybe a way to point it out in a single equation or so, or at least a form little bit shorter than what I have written?
For example, I'm not even sure, if this $x_n^m$ is allowed, as one might mistake the $m$ for a "normal" exponent.

Comment: Looks like the problems are completely independent. Usually, by rolling horizon, I would expect some complicating constraints. I would call this a problem with a block diagonal structure (each block indicated by t). As the problems are completely independent you can solve the sub-problems even in parallel

Comment: In addition to what Erwin said, a typical rolling horizon problem will have starting conditions (initial inventory levels, for instance) that will be dependent on the solution from the previous problem. These would be part of the "complicating constraints" Erwin mentioned.

Comment: Ah ok, thank you for your hints! :) Yeah I see, the example was not perfectly choosen. But it wasn't so much about the example -- I just used it to show what I have seen happening to the matrices. What is more important to me: the steps that I have described above the example. Are they correct? Or have I missed an important step?